# What letter is not found in Bentching 

Tags: blessing, riddle, aleph-bet-letters

Which letter of the alef-beis isn't found in bentching and what is its significance?

Comment: http://www.arachim.org/ArticleDetail.asp?ArticleID=630

Comment: Tashbetz Katan 315 already notes this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Elya Rabba (Orach Chaim 185) notes that in Birchas Hamazon all the letters of the Aleph Beis appear with the exception of the "Ende Fei." The Elya Rabbah explains that according to the esoteric teachings of kabala the "Ende Fei" is associated with demons and harmful spirits. Chazal purposely omitted the "Ende Fei" to underscore that the intense holiness of this
blessing does not allow for a trace of anything harmful or impure.

Comment: Nitpick: Ende *Fei*. There is no such thing as an Ende Pei.

Comment: Pu Pu Pu Oif Dich!

Comment: Fi Fie Fo Fum...

Comment: The association is so ingrained that when people want a 'pey' פּ sound at the end of a word in modern Hebrew that they (unnaturally) use a non-final pey, e.g. the kid's TV network 'Hop', הופּ, http://www.hop.co.il/ . Using a final 'fey' ף is simply understood as an 'eff' sound.

Comment: @Dave See Mishlei 30:6 for the only final Pei in Tanach.

Comment: @DoubleAA - I stand corrected! There is *almost* no such thing as a final Pei.

Comment: @IsaacMoses not constructive, huh?

Comment: On Purim, there is a fei sofis in bentsching.