# Can demons (shedim) masquerade Bas Kols?

Tags: hearing, sheidim-demons, bas-kol

Is it possible for Shedim to masquerade Bas Kols to decieve people , like making people feel that it is Bas kohl but in reality is from Shedim?

Comment: if you are a pure and clean holy man, the shedim have no power over you as brought down in shaarei kedusha. see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/48552/1857

Comment: @ray correct but the question asked is different.

Comment: @narnia how so? it says there, they only have power over someone who is not clean of sin

Comment: @ray I am not a pure and holy man and shedim may have power over me. How do I discern whether I am hearing Shedim or God?

Comment: @ClintEastwood in that case you wont have access to bat kols

Comment: So what if I know that I am near the cut off of being holy enough to hear bas colls and what I hear could be either one?

Answer (score 2):

[This question and answer](http://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=6615) from yeshiva.co might be of some interest to you. Basically, even if one were to accept the premise that shedim are actual, physical beings (which isn't unanimously accepted), they still don't have free will. They are required to do God's will in much the same way the Satan has no free will and can just do God's will.

In any case, the Talmud says if you don't worry about them, they can't affect you. So anybody who is on a high enough level to cause a Bat Kol to address him would presumably also be on a high enough level to not be affected by shedim.