# Peh at the end of a word

Tags: hebrew, aleph-bet-letters

Is there any where in Tanach a word that ends with a "feh sofit" (the form of the letter feh/peh that comes at the end of a word)  but has the sound of a "peh" (and not "feh".)

Similarly I would ask if there is any place in "rabbinical writings" (not modern hebrew) that has a word ending in (and with the sound of) a "peh"? Whether it be spelled with a "peh sofit" or a "regular peh" together with a dagesh (to identify that it's a "peh" sound.)

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3919/what-letter-is-not-found-in-bentching#comment17544_3920

Comment: @DoubleAA Why isn't there a dagash in every print?

Comment: What do you mean? I'm not aware of anyone arguing about the existence of that dagesh. It could always be there is a typo somewhere I suppose.

Comment: @DoubleAA I looked in at least 2 other prints (aside from the one on chabad) in shul today and didn't see it either...I will look in more...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> אַל תּוֹסְףְּ עַל דְּבָרָיו פֶּן יוֹכִיחַ בְּךָ וְנִכְזָבְתָּ.‏
>   ([Mishlei 30:6](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94%3a%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99_%D7%9C_%D7%95))

I believe that this is the only example in Tanakh, and that this does not occur in the classical Rabbinical writings. There is a general rule that beged kefet letters (בג"ד כפ"ת) never have a dagesh kal at the end of a word except for words inflected similarly to the word תּוֹסְףְּ in the verse above.

Comment: Wow! A new fact to add to my Biblical trivia. It's more common with kaf (e.g. וַיֵּֽבְךְּ + inflected forms), and of course happens with tav all the time (e.g. אָתְּ and associated verb forms). The only word I know with final dalet degusha is the plant נֵרְדְּ in Shir haShirim. It doesn't happen (to my knowledge) with bet or gimmel.

Comment: What about the end of the second birkat kohanim? ויחנך

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman That's dagesh chazak, not dagesh kal.

Comment: @Noam There are plenty of examples of final dalet kaf or taf with degeshim, but none of gimmel, only one of pay and two of bet.

Comment: Why is the dagash missing in many prints,  see here: chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16401

Comment: @Yehoshua I suspect that because it is so rare, some editions are not careful to include it or mistakenly leave it out.

Comment: @DoubleAA, where are the two examples of bet?

Comment: @JoshuaPearl וישב ממנו שבי is the one I remember offhand.